# How to create simple website using CouchDB only?

Tags: couchdb

Where do I get a tutorial to create a simple website using CouchDB only without any other scripting language. Is it possible to store the HTML, CSS and the Javascript within the document?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can store HTML, CSS and Javascript in view documents in CouchDB. Check free online book: http://guide.couchdb.org/

Answer (score 1):

Surprised no one else mentioned this but you can create a "couchapp" which sounds like exactly what you want. CoudchDB will serve up the HTML,CSS, images, scripts directly. http://couchapp.org/page/index

Comment: The link is dead, now it seems this page is more relevant https://couchapp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/